# Should I create a new Windows Live ID for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-live

Currently I'm using a local account to log into Windows 8. Back when I was setting up my Windows Phone for the first time I used my existing WL ID and it imported all my MSN Messenger contacts (which I found rather irritating as the set of my MSN contacts is pretty much disjoint from the set of people I call on the phone). I ended up resetting it and setting up again.

So now I'm wondering whether I should use the same Live ID I have on my phone for Windows 8 or create a new one to avoid unexpected consequences regarding data that is already associated.

Side question would probably be: What exactly is associated with my Windows Live ID already and would be used or altered by Windows 8? My guess would be at least

- Contacts
- Calendar data
- SkyDrive

Anything else?

Comment: All of the above would be synced.  Why don't you resolve your disjoint with your contacts?

Comment: Check this Website to know what kind of data is associated with your id: https://choice.microsoft.com/data/

Comment: Ramhound, because I chat with different people than I call on the phone? For a start it's mostly the difference between people in my country and people everywhere else.